# Geospatial querying with Array parameter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Would it be possible?
I need to run query my collection more than one parameter like an Array. It can be coordinates or GeoJSON array. It doesn't matter.

For instance

```
coordinates: [ [3.45855, 18.154265], [4.13515, 22.181822] ]
GeoJSON: [ 
    {"type":"Point", "coordinates":[3.45855, 18.154265]},
    {"type":"Point", "coordinates":[4.13515, 22.181822]},
    {"type":"Point", "coordinates":[5.45833, 24.154888]}   
]
```

I know [I cannot use `$or` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-and-geospatial-queries) with geospatial queries.

But I cannot use $in operator too. If my collection's a sample document like the below, how can I query my collection using one of the above arrays?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54db485b72273a96985dafb7"),
    "firstname" : "John",
    "lastname" : "Doe",
    "location" : {
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                40.937066, 
                29.326202
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit:

Actually, I need to use $near and $maxDistance operators in my Array Query. I can find result of a given only one `Point` parameter properly like the following. It works;

```
{'location.geometry': 
    { 
        $near: 
        {
            $geometry: GeoJSON[0],
            $maxDistance: 500  
        }
    }
}
```

But I need a query like the below;

```
{'location.geometry': 
    { 
        $near: 
        {
            $geometry: { $in: GeoJSON },
            $maxDistance: 500  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what geo query you want to run with those points? Are the points defining a polygon or you want one geo operation run per point?

Comment: Hello @wdberkeley, I've tried to edit my question according to your questions. Yes, in fact I want one geo operation run per point.
Is there any chance to find documents that are near 500 meters to a coordinate of a given array like the above?

Comment: Sure, but you need to run one query per point. You can't batch them or stuff them together into one operation.

Comment: Thanks @wdberkeley, hopefully in the future we can batch geospatial query :) My solution works with good performance for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overcome the issue using [async javascript library](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilsttest-fn-callback) like the below;

```
    var totalCount = 0
            index = 0;

    async.whilst(
        function(){  
            return index < GeoJSON.length 
        },
        function(callback) { // main function
            var geoQuery = myCollection.find();
            geoQuery.where({
                'location.geometry': {
                    $near: {
                        $geometry: GeoJSON[index],
                        $maxDistance: 500
                    }
                }
            })
            .count(function(err, count){
                if(err) callback(err);
                else {      
                    totalCount += count;
                    index++;
                    callback(null)
                }
            })
        },
        function (err){ // callback function
            res.send({ 
                error: err, 
                count: totalCount 
            })
        }
    );
```